# Adding custom back button on navigation bar

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar

I am trying to add custom back button on navigation bar but it is not working below is my code

```
-(void)addLeftButton
{
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back.png"];

    UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [aButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    aButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width,   buttonImage.size.height);

    UIBarButtonItem *aBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aButton];

   [aButton addTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

   self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = aBarButtonItem;
}
```

Please tell what's wrong with this code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
-(void)addLeftButton
{
     UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back.png"];

     UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

     [aButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     aButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width,   buttonImage.size.height);

     UIBarButtonItem *aBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aButton];

     [aButton addTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

     [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:aBarButtonItem];
}
```

Comment: this is for left button not back button @Developer.iOS

Comment: it means u don't want to put back button at left side of navigation ??

Comment: actually backButton and leftButton are two different things in iOS7

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that i have used to create custom backbutton

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set the custom back button

    //add the resizable image
    UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"backbtn.png"]
                            resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 13, 0, 5)];

    //create the button and assign the image
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    MSLabel *lbl = [[MSLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 4, 65, 28)];
    lbl.text = @"Settings";
    lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0];
    lbl.numberOfLines = 0;

    lbl.lineHeight = 12;
    lbl.verticalAlignment = MSLabelVerticalAlignmentMiddle;
    lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];

    [button addSubview:lbl];

    //set the frame of the button to the size of the image (see note below)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, buttonImage.size.height);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //create a UIBarButtonItem with the button as a custom view
    UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;

}

-(void)back {
    // Tell the controller to go back
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This  code will resize your image so it can fit the text.
You can also put this button in any method.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add action to your button. So you need to add action to your button. For more info see in the below code..

```
-(void)addLeftButton
{
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back.png"];

    UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [aButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    aButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width,   buttonImage.size.height);

    UIBarButtonItem *aBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aButton];

    [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backBtnPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; // -------- Edit here -----

   self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = aBarButtonItem;
}  

-(void)backBtnPressed
{
       [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Setting action doesn't matters @Dharambir